# Curves wrong filled when importing svg

Tags: bezier-curves, import

I'm working with illustrator and exporting as SVG this graphic.

This is how it looks in illustrator (and how I wanted to be). The green part is all fill, no strokes. The white is all canvas.

[image: Illustrator Vector]

But I'm getting this at Blender.

[image]

It fills the center of the image, not the border as a stroke.
If you have any clue...thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most likely the issue is that you have two different curves in the SVG file and they got imported as different objects, so they are filled differently.

[image]

In edit mode select both curves (select one first and then press <kbd>shift</kbd> and select the other) and join them pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd>

Now the fill should work fine:

[image]