# Fill along the front of a path of a bezier curve

Tags: path, svg

I have an SVG logo, which I will import into Blender. I'm trying to think how to have the curve fill (not outline) fill up from left to right.

I think the following steps put me on the right track, but struggling how to full resolve this:

1. Import SVG to Blender
2. Convert Curve to Mesh for the imported object
3. Extrude object (to make it 3D)

That's as far as I know how to do, then I think the following steps are needed (which I don't know how to do).

4. Create an outline of the 3D object (with no fill)
5. Draw a path across the object with timeline
6. Animate the path being filled

Would be grateful for any ideas how to achieve this.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to convert to mesh to extrude. The outline should be easy if you keep the object as curves (just disable the fill options by setting the curve fill to "none") To fill the path you just need to animate the bevel factor. To help you better please add images that show what you have so far.

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61552/how-do-you-import-svg-without-a-fill/61554#61554

Comment: also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3171/how-to-animate-multiple-lines/3178#3178

Comment: Yeah don't convert to mesh unless strictly necessary, it will ruin your spline for no good reason. AS Cegaton mentioned you can animate bevel factor, not so trivial to animate a fill effect though

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[image]

Don't needlessly convert your bezier to a mesh unless strictly necessary, it is a destructive process and will ruin your model and the benefits of using curve objects.

For an animated outline and fill effect you will need two independent copies of your original SVG imported curve object.

**Animated Outline**

For the animated outline make sure a new copy of your original curve is set to 2D, non-cyclic (i.e. open) and has no fill. Then add a *Bevel Width* to it as desired then animate the *Bevel Factor Start* or *Bevel Factor End* property by keyframing it.

[image]

**Animated Fill**

For the fill animation a new independent copy of the original curve is needed. Extrude it and bevel it as desired, by using the builtin *Curve Extrude* and *Bevel* properties.

Afterwards add a *Build Modifier* to it, and adjust the animation parameters as desired. You can see the result by scrubbing the time line.

[image]

To animate fill followed by extrusion afterwards, keyframe the "fill process" of the *Build* modifier so it starts and ends first, then animate the *Extrude* parameter of the curve by keyframing it, so it only starts after the build concludes

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the detailed explanation. I tried the 1st and it worked, and tried the 2nd (seems more like what Im looking for), however, I couldn't get it to work. I have a line (so it's not an enclosed shape), so I have to turn off cyclic. Basically what happens is that it fills in the line in the first pass (on the timeline) and then next moves onto the extrude (so it fills in first, then extrudes), I was hoping for it to fill and extrude at the same time, Im wondering if you know of any way to do that?

Comment: @Ke. like [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3178/935)?

Comment: You might have to animate the "build process" first, and only then animate the extrusion parameter by keyframing it, after the fill animation is concluded.

Comment: Answer updated to reflect that