# How can I create text with a black outline as seen in anime subtitles?

Tags: interface, text-object

[image]

Ive tried a few different ways to do this but they all take way too long.

Comment: Why are you making subtitles inside Blender? See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg

Comment: i need to track the txt to people so i use blender

Comment: Blender does have what is called "Freestyle".  I use it for subtitles when the need arises.  If you can't get it going I can place an answer here, or someone else will.  It works well.  The render time for each subtitle is a only a second or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using text objects in 3D view then you could bevel the text and use a texture to color the edges black. There is no additional render overhead from Freestyle renderer and this is using the Blender Internal render engine.

[image: render outline]

[image: bevel]

[image: bevel settings]

Notice that I have altered the direction of the texture blend by using the mapping values for X axis.

[image: material]