# How can I Import this text in blender as a 2D object?

Tags: texturing, import, image

[image: Text in blue with black outlines: "Like this"]

I need to track 2D text like the image shown above. Is there a way to import this into blender without the white background?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can i create text with black outline like seen in the subtitals of some anime?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93375/how-can-i-create-text-with-black-outline-like-seen-in-the-subtitals-of-some-anim)

Comment: Please don't ask the same question more than once

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos could you take another look?

Comment: You could just make text and edit it in edit more then add a blue material to it.

Comment: look in to importing SVG. not a great solution, but really the only way to import it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways I know of...

Use Gimp or another photo editor to select the white background and make it transparent. Then save or export as a PNG with an alpha channel. Then in Blender user preferences. Turn on the import images as planes addon. Once you have that done choose import as plane and the image will come in without the white.

The other would be to use Illustrator or inskape and trace the bitmap remove the white area by deleting it. Save the traced vector as an SVG. In Blender turn on the import SVG addon in the user preferences. Then go and import the saved SVG.

The SVG way gives you an object you could extrude as well.

Comment: im using clip studio paint  and they dont same pngs with an alpha chanel, that the layers arew just transparent. it there a way to get around that?