# Freestyle outline similar to viewport outline?

Tags: rendering, shaders, bezier-curves, freestyle, outliner

I'm trying to make a title sequence where the text 'inflates' to wipe transition into the first scene. I'm using a curve object with an emission shader to do this and increasing bevel depth to inflate the text. Trouble is, I want the text to have an outline that follows the silhouette of the object but alas, freestyle is giving me a lot of grief.

Coincidentally, the way that blender outlines objects in the viewport editor is EXACTLY what I want, but no combination of freestyle's edge type detection is working. Any way to get around this or is it just a lost cause?

[image: Viewport Outline (What I want)]

[image: What Freestyle is giving me]

[image: What freestyle's giving me]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-an-svg/82200#82200