# Working with imported SVG, converted to mesh and create new clean mesh geometry

Tags: modeling

As a graphic designer I work a lot with  Ai and SVG files. So what would be the best workflow for importing SVG files, turning them into a mesh, clean up the messy geometry, and then build a new and clean geometry for that converted mesh?

My goal is to shrinkwrap it onto another rounded mesh. But when I do it like this; Import SVG, Convert to mesh, and then I use "dissolve face" to clean up the messy geometry, then I can't use subdivide cause nothing happens and no new geometry is added. Nor does it do anything when using the subdivision surface modifier.

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are you converting to mesh? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-a-bezier-curve/82200#82200

Comment: Because I want to shrinkwrap it onto another rounded mesh. But when I do it like this; Import SVG, Convert to mesh, and then I use "dissolve face" to clean up the messy geometry, then I can't use subdivide cause nothing happens and no new geometry is added. Nor does it do anything when using the subdivision surface modifier.

Thnx

Comment: You can project a grid on the object in order to subdivide it with the help of the Knife Project tool, see my tuto here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIPOrsGi2aY#t=7m40s

Comment: Yea my bad, I thought no further details needed if some one just has an answer for my question above ;)
This is the situation, I have this face shape that I want to shrinkwrap to this body mesh. And ideally I would just import the face shape svg (cause I have the character made in Illustrator) and not have to re-draw all these elements in Blender.

But when working with SVG, (and want to use the shrinkwrap modifier to stick it to the curved body mesh) I have to convert it to mesh right? And then the new converted mesh needs clean geometry to do a good shrinkwarp? https://imgur.com/a/2fe2b1d

Comment: I think someone already answered your question, no?

Comment: Hey Moonboots, yes you and The Kalaakaar gave me some options to try. Which I tried and had didn;t work out for me, as I also answered in that post :) So I tried to ask the question SVG to MESH to clean Geometry apart from the Shrinkwrap issue over here.

Comment: The model that I found in your other question has a lot of duplicated vertices. Remove *Only Faces* (so Blender doesn't freeze for the next step), then select all and do a *Merge By Distance* (key M) to reduce the 41k vertices down to 1.5k. Then do a *Mesh > Vertices > Limit Dissolve* with 7.5°. Now you have only a few vertices left and you can do a retopology of the SVG. Ian McGlasham has a series about this here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TC-qyGzRyeQ&list=PLoSyNsQF2hFDX8gsIhcnl2j2gvhNkhPZk

Comment: @Blunder Thnx mate, gonna give that a try also!