Create a filling between a frontline (path)

I have created a path (frontline) and i animated it so a part of it moves according to keyframes, now i want to create a filling inside of it to resemble a country like shown below, how can i do it?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/fill-along-the-front-of-a-path-of-a-bezier-curve/82200#82200
