How to fill face of closed shape imported as DXF?
How can I simply fill/make a faced of this closed shape, so that I may extrude the face?

I import a dxf and converted the imported curve to a mesh
I'm able to open the dxf in SolidWorks and it recognizes it as closed shape and I'm able to to do basic extrude, screenshot below:

In Blender, I've used the "F" command (Vertex ->"New edge/face from vertices") on simple shapes circles, rectangles, etc, but it doesn't work on this irregular closed shape. To make sure I selected the entire shape I would pick the mesh in the Outliner then hit "A" for select all, but when I hit "F" it just fills in a sliver of the entire shape, as shown in the the close screenshot, the red arrow points to the small rectangular area that gets filled in.
Thanks for any help on this.


https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/82200/19307

This does not work for the mesh
