# extrude svg with no fill

Tags: extrude, svg, splines

I'm drawing splines in photoshop, exporting as AI, converting online to SVG and importing to blender to extrude and work on them. But they have no fill, so they won't extrude the way I usually extrude SVGs. I know I can fill them in inkscape and reexport, but I believe there is a way to extrude them directly in Blender. Am I right?

Comment: If you have a sample SVG, I could give it a go. I use them frequently for my rig control shapes.

Comment: OK, how do I attach it here?

Comment: Not really in fact, I'm not trying to import AI, I'm trying to extrude SVG which has no fill, without using Inkscape.

Comment: Edit your question, on top of the text input, there is a bunch of icons. Link out to an external source or stick them in a .blend file.

Comment: SVGs get imported as curves. In the curves properties menu you can set them as **filled** using front, back or both. https://i.stack.imgur.com/gszbM.png

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/imported-svg-files-does-not-show-up/8018#8018 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46639/curves-wrong-filled-when-importing-svg/46641#46641 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61552/how-do-you-import-svg-without-a-fill/61554#61554